# How do I fill a 2d char array? c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Im trying to fill a 2d char array with blank spaces to get rid of the junk that comes up when you call it.
Everytime I try and compile this i get:
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char [2]' to 'char'
At no point in my code did I (intentionally) make anything a constant. 
Can some explain to me why this is not working?

```
void CreateArr(char arrv[5][5])
{

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)    
{
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++) 
    {
         arrv[i][j] = " "; 
    }

}
}


int main()
{
char foo[5][5];
CreateArr(foo);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single quotes, `" "` is a string literal, you want a char literal which is written like `' '`

Comment: @user3331346 Np, easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 1):

or you can use memset.

```
memset(arrv, ' ', sizeof(char) * 5 * 5);
```

It will not work in a structure / class with different type member.